# sort the user input value got correct with error message

Tags: ruby

Below is my code

```
a = Array.new(10, 0)

(1..5).each do |t|
    a[gets.to_i] += 1
end

(0..10).each do |i|
   (1..a[i]).each do |j|
    if j>0
      puts i
    end
  end
end
```

when I input 5 3 2 2 8 , the return value will be 2 2 3 5 8 .
but I got some error which show

```
practice.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>': bad value for range(ArgumentError)
from /practice.rb:7:in `each'
from /practice.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the range `..` operator includes the last value in the range, so in your case:

```
(0..10).to_a
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

In the last loop through, you ask for the range of `(1..a[10])` and since `a` is a zero based index, 10 is `nil` so `(1..nil)` fails.

Instead, you can use `...` in range, which allows you to omit the last value, as such:

```
(0...10).to_a
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So you can change the top of this loop and it will work as expected.

```
(0...10).each do |i|
  ..
end
```